# What's the algorithm for unscrambling this image

Tags: algorithms, image-processing

I have an image that has been scrambled using this algorithm:

- Pixel 1-32 of line 1 are correctly placed in line 1
- Pixel 33-64 of line 1 belong to pixel 1-32 of line 2
- Pixel 65-96 of line 2 belong to pixel 1-32 of line 3
- Pixel 1025-1056 of line 2 belong to pixel 33-64 of line 1
- Pixel 1057-1088 of line 2 belong to pixel 33-64 of line 2

How can I find out where the pixels of the image go in the new image mathematically by using the variables defined?

- height = 800
- width = 1024
- size = 32

Hope this is clear enough :) Any help appreciated!